# How to use @IonicPage() with ion-tabs?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I need my Ionic application to have URL for each page. I have a page with ion-tabs (TabsPage):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  template: `
    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab root="HomePage" tabTitle="Home" tabUrlPath="home-tab" tabIcon=""></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab root="NewsPage" tabTitle="News" tabUrlPath="news-tab" tabIcon=""></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
 `
})
export class TabsPage {
}
```

And I have home page (one of the tabs):

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  template: `
    some content
  `
})
export class HomePage {
}
```

When home page is opened then URL is: `http://localhost/#/home-tab/home`

But when I reload the page then URL is: `http://localhost/#/home`

I don't understand why "home-tab" disappears. After page reload there is no tabs.